# How to find $Z_y(x_0,y_0)$ if $Z(x, y) = Z(x(u,v), y(u,v)) =T(u,v)$ and $u=xy$, $v={y\over x}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

> Calculate $Z_y(2,1.5)$ if  $Z(x, y) = Z(x(u,v), y(u,v)) =T(u,v)$ and $u=xy$, $v={y\over x}$.

I think that according to chain rule:
$$
T_u=Z_xx_u+Z_yy_u\\
T_v=Z_xx_v+Z_yy_v
$$
Using implicit differentiation and product rule:
$$
1=x_uy+xy_u\\
1=\frac{x_vy-xy_v}{y^2}\\
0=x_vy+xy_v\\
0=\frac{x_uy-xy_u}{y^2}
$$
which yields:
$$
x_v=y\\
y_v=-\frac{y}{2x}
$$
So at point $(2,1.5)$ we have $T_v=1.5Z_x+0.375Z_y$.

But I can't progress further because when trying to calculate $x_u$:
$$
x_u=\frac{1+xy_u}{y} \quad\text{from 1st equation}\\
\text{plugging this into the last equation:}\quad 0=\frac{1}{y}\implies y=0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use the chain rule.

\begin{align*} T(u,v)=T(u(x,y),v(x,y)) \Rightarrow Z_y = \frac{\partial T}{\partial y} = \begin{pmatrix} T_u & T_v \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}  u_y \\ v_y\end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using differentials:
$$dZ=dT=T_u du+T_v dv, $$
and also 
$$du=u_x d x+u_y dy, \\ dv=v_x dx+v_ydy .$$
Thus
$$dZ=(T_u u_x+T_v v_x) dx+(T_uu_y+T_v v_y)dy,$$
which gives
$$Z_y(x_0,y_0)=x_0T_u+\frac{T_v}{x_0}. $$
The partial derivatives $T_u,T_v$ are calculated at the point $(u_0,v_0)$ which corresponds to $(x_0,y_0)$.